Ресурсы про память (стек, куча, сегмент кода, данных.)
Я сейчас изучаю C++. Мне нужна подробная информация о разделах в памяти, ни как не могу найти нормальный русскоязычный ресурс. Везде рассказывают только про стек и кучу. Помогите пожалуйста, если есть ссылки на русскоязычные статьи или ресурсы, может лекции в youtube.
Еще маленький вопрос, как и где будет храниться строковый массив объявленный глобально (например: string nums[]{"один"}, {"два"}, {"три"}....).

как и где будет храниться строковый массив : в статической памяти процесса.

Почитайте книгу Таненбаума про операционные системы, там целый раздел посвящен организации памяти.

@evo Не факт. Зависит от того, как реализован string.

@Harry если объявлен глобально и сразу инициализирован, например:
#include 
#include 
std::string nums[]{"один"}, {"два"}, {"три"};
int main()
{
.........
}

Даже в этом варианте может быть размещение самих строк в динамической памяти. По крайней мере в стандарте, где строка не constexpr :)

@Harry понял, то есть, вообще литералы хранятся в сегменте данных, но если их слишком много, то компилятор делает указатели на кучу, вместо сегмента данных, правильно?

Литералы - это одно, массив string - другое, а данные в string - это уже третье :) Вопрос же был о массиве, а не литералах.
